# iOS App clip - disable invocation from previous URL

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, swiftui, apple-appclips

According to the documentation, for app clips:

**If a user returns to a previously launched App Clip from the App Library or Spotlight, the App Clip uses the invocation URL that it previously used to launch the App Clip.**

Is there a way to see whether the invocation URL that is passed to the app is simply the cached URL from a e.g. Spotlight launch vs. whether it has actually come from an app clip invocation method like NFC/QR?

Alternatively, is there a way to disable this caching altogether?